# Extracting compressed image data from bag file results in doubled up or dropped frames

Tags: rosbag, ros-kinetic, image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to extract compressed images from a bag file. Here is my launch file:

```
<launch>   
  <!-- Play Bag File -->   
  <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="rosbag" required="true" args="-r
  0.2 /media/nick/Samsung\ USB/bag_files/_2018-07-20-16-30-09.bag"/>

  <!-- Uncompress images -->   
  <node pkg="image_transport" type="republish" name="decompress_node" args="compressed in:=/webcam1/image out:=/webcam1/image" />

  <!-- Extract images -->
  <node name="extract" pkg="image_view" type="extract_images" respawn="false" required="true" output="screen" cwd="ROS_HOME">
    <remap from="image" to="/webcam1/image"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

This results in some frames not being saved and some frames being saves multiple times. Also a lot of frames are saved out of order so the video I make out of the frames is really choppy.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298180/extracting-compressed-image-data-from-bag-file-results-in-doubled-up-or-dropped-frames/) by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 545 on 2018-07-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are re-publishing the decompressed images on the same topic as the originals.

```
in:=/webcam1/image out:=/webcam1/image
```

So your file extraction node is receiving both, possibly with a time delay pushing them out of order. If you use a different topic name for the decompressed images it should solve this.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2018-07-23**:
It appears that image transport adds /compressed to the topic name.

For instance when I change it to "in:=/webcam1/image/compressed out:=/webcam1/image" this is what I get in rostopic list.

/webcam1/image
/webcam1/image/compressed
/webcam1/image/compressed/compressed

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-07-23**:
Try running the launch file without the bag file playback. rostopic echo each of these topics then publish a single image to the input topic. Looking closely at what happens may shed some light on what's going on.